# how to escape double dash -- in DokuWiki

Tags: formatting, wiki, dokuwiki

I would like to enter e double dash `--` in unicode formatted syntax in DokuWiki but it gets rendered as a long dash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `%%--%%` to prevent rendering DokuWiki markup.